# Why doesn't my "if" statement work?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, switch-statement

I can't get my `if` statement to work when I attempt to populate 9 category tables from a separate master products table.

Here is the code I tried...none of the tables populated with this.

```
foreach ($tables as $category_table)
{
    if ($category_table = "my_products_dsdi_apparel")
    {
    $category_products_image = "'%images_products/apparel/%'";
    }
    ...

mysql_query
("
INSERT INTO $category_table
SELECT * FROM zen_products 
WHERE products_image LIKE $category_products_image
ORDER BY products_id ASC
");

}
```

So, I tried the SWITCH function and it works.

```
foreach ($tables as $category_table)
{
    switch ($category_table)
    {
    case "my_products_dsdi_apparel":
        $category_products_image = "'%images_products/apparel/%'";
        break;
... 

    default:
        echo "It failed again!";
    }

mysql_query
("
INSERT INTO $category_table
SELECT * FROM zen_products 
WHERE products_image LIKE $category_products_image
ORDER BY products_id ASC
");

}
```

Why doesn't the "if" scenario work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use '==' i.e. comparison operator instead of'=' i.e assignment operator.
```

your **if** will look like.

```
if ($category_table == "my_products_dsdi_collectibles")
```

Comment: @MikeLittle can you please elaborate because i guess u faced issues because of wrong if statement implementation.you were actually assigning values and not comparing it.change all if statements.

Comment: @MikeLittle i only meant in if statment.your switch code looks good.wait i will have a look.

Comment: @Letmesee no need to be rude.we all start at some level.

Comment: @MikeLittle your question is little ambiguous,if its ok with you can you please share the tables and the desired output you want in your question.

Comment: Mr coder...thanks for real help. Does the IF need to be "if"...I'm new to MYSQL and PHP but have used visual basic extensively.

Comment: @MikeLittle coventionally 'yes'.

Comment: It's late and I'm tired...will give this a shot tomorrow and repost back here if it works. Thanks again for the positive feedback.

Comment: There was too much info to digest in the original question. So, I am breaking it down into smaller pieces and posting different questions for each problem I'm having. The if code work too if I use == instead of = ! So, this answer gets my vote for this issue! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why not define an associative array?

Would make the code more readable.

**EDIT**

Two off the list to get the idea

```
$lookup = array(
"my_products_dsdi_apparel" => "'%images_products/apparel/%'",
"my_products_dsdi_at_home" => "'%images_products/at_home/%'",
...
);
$category_products_image = $lookup[$category_table];
```

Comment: Please do...since I have no clue what you are talking about. An example or link to one would be useful!

Comment: Thanks Ed...It looks like this might be what I need with fixing the second half of my issue. Will let you know if it solve the problem.